# Uncertainty propagation time difference

Tags: kinematics, measurements, error-analysis, data-analysis

So for an experiment we gathered time data. It a rolling object, where t2 and t1 are measurements of one whole roll of circumference. We estimated time uncertainty at 5 ms.

​

So then estimation of uncertainty on time difference we calculated as $ \sqrt{2}*dt$ uncertainty.

​

To calculate the speed we have circumference = c, $c/(t2-t1)$. To calculate the uncertainty on speed we used the propagation of uncertainty formula, sum of squares etc.

$dc =$ uncertainty in circumference

$dv = \sqrt{ ( dc/dt )^2 + (c/dt^2)^2 *dt^2)}$

​

However if we calculate acceleration we get really big uncertainties. Is this the proper way to calculate the uncertainties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a function $y=f(a,b)$ and we have uncertainties $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ in its parameters, the uncertainty of $y$ is given by
$$
\Delta y = \sqrt{\left(\frac{df}{da}\sigma_a\right)^2 + 
\left(\frac{df}{db}\sigma_b\right)^2 }
$$
This formula is true if the two parameters are not correlated, as is the case for the velocity your are interested in.
As you know the (average) velocity is given by $v=s/t$. Thus, using the above formula the uncertainty in the velocity is given by
\begin{align}
\sigma_y = \sigma_v &= \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dv}{ds}\sigma_s\right)^2 + 
\left(\frac{dv}{dt}\sigma_t\right)^2
} \\
&=\sqrt{ \left(\frac{1}{t}\sigma_s\right)^2 + 
\left(\frac{s}{t^2}\sigma_t\right)^2
} \\
\end{align}
Please note that I strictly distinguish between the results of my measurements

- $s$: the measured distance
- $t$: the measured time

and the accompanied uncertainties $\sigma_t$ and $\sigma_s$. In addition, the above formula is only valid if we consider random changes and not systematic errors (which is often called *bias*). Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps but this was my idea. I think the measurements were not exact enough maybe. Thanks. By the way, how do you know for certain that the measurements aren't correlated?

Comment: If we do not find a convincing argument that two variables/parameters are correlated we usually assume that they are independent. I personally do not know a hypothesis test which test for independence.